# Adding Do Loop in femtolisp or defining a do loop macro common lisp

Tags: scheme, lisp, femtolisp

I am using femtolisp in my project but it doesn't  support the do loop .Can any one guide me how to add do loop functionality in femtolisp or can i define a macro for do loop in common lisp.

Comment: Why is this tagged "C" ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Femtolisp *does* provide a [`do` macro](https://github.com/JeffBezanson/femtolisp/blob/2923137ef047b401d560766537782f60e67f9a0c/system.lsp#L488). For reference, here's its implementation:

```
(define-macro (do vars test-spec . commands)
  (let ((loop (gensym))
        (test-expr (car test-spec))
        (vars  (map car  vars))
        (inits (map cadr vars))
        (steps (map (lambda (x)
                      (if (pair? (cddr x))
                          (caddr x)
                          (car x)))
                    vars)))
    `(letrec ((,loop (lambda ,vars
                       (if ,test-expr
                           (begin
                             ,@(cdr test-spec))
                           (begin
                             ,@commands
                             (,loop ,.steps))))))
       (,loop ,.inits))))
```

Comment: Yup , But i am using its tiny repo that does not have do implementation